# Anchor links just won't work

Tags: html

I am working on a bespoke WordPress build and for some reason, I just cannot get some anchor links to work. It's driving me potty and I just don't know what the problem is.

I have discovered, static anchor links are working fine (the back to top button works). However, I am using Advanced Custom Fields to generate ID's for the anchor tags. The IDs are generating correctly, but won't work as anchor tags.

Anyone have any ideas? The bit I am referring to is the service boxes near the bottom of the page. The idea being you click on these and that they will take you to the services page, and down to the relevant section.

The markup I am using is:

```
<ul class="cf">
    <li>
        <div>
            <a href="/services/#dimensional-surveys">
                <div class="filter"></div>
                <img width="500" height="600" src="pexels-photo-175771-500x600.jpeg" class="attachment-feature size-feature" alt="" />                                       
                <h3>3D Dimensional Surveys</h3>
            </a>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>

<ul class="service-list cf">
    <li id="#dimensional-surveys">
        <div class="feature" style="background-image:url(pexels-photo-175771.jpeg);">
        </div>
     </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: There is nothing between the anchor tags. You open and close it immediately, so there's nothing to click.

Comment: Note that questions involving "please look at my site here" are at risk of closure, since if the question relies on a link that will soon be fixed, it will not be useful for future readers. Can you bring more code into the question?

Comment: @qirel I haven't put content in as I was trying to keep code example simple and uncluttered.

Comment: @halfer I have added relevant code above so providing both the code and a live example.

Comment: Here dev.charlyanderson.co.uk/MEA/services/ there is no ancor named `example`?!?

Comment: [Related Meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428).

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions it was an example - I have updated with full urls

Comment: @CharlyAnderson Please post your *exact* code. Without it, there might be obvious issues that can't be seen. Even still, there is **nothing** between the opening and closing anchor tag! You need `<a href="/..">TEXT OR SOMETHING</a>`, if you close the anchor immediately (`</a>`) it will basically have no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the # from id and it will work.

```
 <a href="/services/#example"></a>
<ul>
<li id="example"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I'd still have a hard time clicking that anchor, though.

Comment: That was it thank you - I knew it would be something simple I was missing. Thanks so much :-)

Answer (score 1):

I have looked at your page

The point where an ancor should jump to should have no `#`

You do: `<li id="#dimensional-surveys">`

But do just `<li id="dimensional-surveys">`

Fix that first and test again.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want the '#' on the anchor:  `<li id="#example"></li>` should be `<li id="example"></li>`